# Single Window Mode (TeXShop) - Forward Search

Tags: texshop, forward-inverse-search

When I am in the "Single Window" mode in TeXShop (In the menu, Window --> Use One Window), I am able to perform a inverse search (Preview --> TeX) but not forward search (TeX --> Preview). Is there a setting that will enable it or is this a bug?

Comment: What version of TeXShop are you using? I see no problem, with a simple example, using the latest version, 3.88.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am using version 3.88 as well but am still facing the problem. I don't know how to create a minimal working example in this case. What would be your advice?

Comment: Sync in either direction requires a Cmd-Click. I assume you are doing that. I also am assuming you mean Sync rather than Search.

Comment: One more thing, is the document you are using a single file or is it distributed?

Comment: Thanks again Herb for patient responses. Indeed, I am using Cmd-Click, I mean sync and not search and it is a single file. Still stumped by this glitch. I did check the Typesetting preference after your comment and changed the sync method to "SyncTex (Tex >=2010); not sure why it was not selected by default. Now, I am able to do forward sync in the single window mode. However, does not circle the text in pdf; it just highlights in yellow. Is that natural behavior?

Comment: It hasn’t circled the text for quite a long time. The Source->Preview sync is not all that accurate so the circle just got ugly. I believe there’s a hidden Preference to go back to the circle but don’t remember what it is.  SyncTeX (TeX >= 2010) is the correct setting for recent TeX distributions.